# Intellij JavaDocs For EE

Tags: intellij-idea

I am able to view JavaDocs for the base Java classes just fine, but for EE class, for example, EntityManager, I cannot get them to appear.

Does anyone know how to get the Enterprise object docs to appear?  I am using Intellij 14.

The 1st screenshot shows my settings, the 2nd, the empty javadocs for EntityManager, and the 3rd, the Map javadoc.

[image: Project Setings]

[image: Entity Manager]

[image: Map for SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your project, and hit *Maven/Download Documentation*. Or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for *Download Documentation*.

You can also go to *Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Maven Importing* and choose to automatically download documentation (and sources) for Maven dependencies.

Btw I'm assuming that you are using Maven from based on the second screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I am using maven.  Thanks very much.

Comment: When I download the documentation and sources, do you know where on the disk it is stored?

Comment: @EdgeCase I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that IntelliJ downloads Maven artifacts with sources and JavaDocs and takes the documentation from there (for instance I have `hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final-sources.jar` containing the sources with JavaDoc in my local Maven repo along with `hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar` containing the compiled code.